# Woocommerce checkout field place inside div

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I can't seem to figure out how to put specific woocommerce checkout field inside a div (not custom field).

Currently it is like this

```
<p ....><label .... ></label><input ... ></p>
```

I would like to place a div around input:

```
<p ....><label .... ></label><div clas="my_div"><input ... ></div></p>
```

Anyone have a solution?

p.s. I am trying to put font Awesome icons inside input. I know i can do it via placeholder but then the icon disappears.
Also i need label to stay above input.

Comment: `<div><label></label><input></input></div>`?

Comment: @aldrin27 No i need to wrap input. Will edit my question to post reason why, maybe someone else did what i want without it.

Comment: So you want to have your input with icons right?

Comment: @aldrin27 yep, but not as a placeholder.

Comment: `<p><label></label><span class="insert here the font awesome class"></span><input/></p>`

Comment: @aldrin27 I get that, but the problem in woocommerce checkout form is that you can't edit form that easily. You can't edit html directly. Thats why my question is woocommerce checkout field. Thanks for the responses

Comment: @dinca , you can also try using jQuery's [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function

Comment: @Anand Yep that can do it :) Thanks! I was trying to find out how the checkout field works but some other day.